Сочетание времён в одном предложении
Корректно ли сочетание в одном предложении однородных сказуемых настоящего и простого будущего времени?
Например, «делает и принесёт», «показывает и устанет» и т.д.
Чувствую, что это неверно, а правила не нашла.

Он выступает на конференции и поделится своим опытом.


Он сейчас выступает на конференции и в рамках этого будет делиться с нами своим опытом. Тут логические времена действий пересекаются - настоящее протяженное и будущее повторяющееся. Грамматически непересекающиеся времена, логически пересекающиеся. Нет проблем.

Есть проблемы.  Где ответ: предложение правильное?  Я  так не думаю, уши режет.  Дайте ссылку на правило и на ваши объяснения тоже.  Ну и примеры из литературы приведите, если уж по-вашему правильно. Хотелось бы, так сказать,  в источниках  почитать и удостовериться.

ТЕОРИЯ
Категория времени в современном русском языке
Глаголы настоящего времени обозначают, что действие совпадает с моментом речи: Я читаю книгу, Ты читаешь книгу. Формы настоящего времени имеются только у глаголов несовершенного вида. Глаголы настоящего времени несовершенного вида обозначают:
(1) действие или состояние, осуществляющееся в момент речи: 
Снова торжественно и мудро шумит надо мной старинный хвойный 
бор (В. Бел.);
(2) действие постоянное (вневременное): Несколько морей 
омывают берега нашей страны;
(3) действие или состояние, выражающее свойство, качество 
лица-предмета: Он славно пишет, переводит (Гр.);
(4) действие, охватывающее некоторый отрезок времени: 
Довольно того, что у каждого из нас хранятся твои стихи 
(Пауст).

Глаголы будущего времени обозначают действие, которое совершается (или совершится) после момента речи. Форма будущего времени от глаголов несовершенного вида сложная: она состоит из спрягаемой формы вспомогательного глагола быть и инфинитива глагола: буду читать. Форма будущего времени от глаголов совершенного вида простая: она совпадает с формой настоящего времени глаголов несовершенного вида: прочитаю, построят.
Для русского глагола характерно употребление форм одного времени в значении другого. Формы настоящего времени в значении будущего употребляются тогда, когда говорящий уверен, что действие обязательно осуществиться в будущем: Я сегодня в крепость после уроков иду (Д. Беляев). Иногда формами настоящего времени передаётся воображаемая автором картина: Ещё один день этого окаянного пекла, — и вот тебе голодная зима, тиф, падает скот, мрут дети (А.Н. Т.).
Транспозиция временных форм глагола в русском языке
Грамматическая форма в русском языке двупланова.  В грамматической форме различаем ее исходное генетическое значение, связанное с ее происхождением, и значения функциональные, т.е. значения, которые форма получает в речевом употреблении. Транспозицией считается использование грамматической формы в таких функциональных значениях, которые в той или иной степени отступают от ее генетического значения.
Грамматическое время конкретизируется в речи в зависимости от ситуации, контекста речи, а так же от лексического значения глагола. Например, форма писал, взятая вне речи, обозначает просто прошедшее, прошедшее недифференцированное. Но в зависимости от обстановки речи и контекста может обозначать: а) прошедшее длительное (я писал это письмо весь день); б) прошедшее длительное прерывистое (я много раз писал ему об этом); в) прошедшее однократное без указания на степень его продолжительности (я уже писал ему об этом).
Будущее в настоящем
Речь идет о простом будущем глаголов, получивших значение совершенного вида.  Конструкция состоит из простого будущего глагола совершенного вида в сочетании с отрицательными словами никак, нигде, никаким образом и т.д.:
Никак не забью гвоздь, не открою окно, не найду этой книги, 
не пойму вас, не решу этой задачи и т.д. Здесь настоящее с 
особым модальным оттенком невозможности: " никак не забью 
гвоздь " = " никак не могу забить гвоздь". В данной 
конструкции выражена невозможность завершить, закончить 
производимое в настоящем времени действие. 

РЕШЕНИЕ

Неправильно: Он выступает на конференции и поделится своим опытом.

Правильно: Он выступит на конференции и поделится своим опытом.
Однородные сказуемые выполняют одинаковую синтаксическую функцию и занимают позицию одного члена предложения. В данном случае оба действия относятся к  одному временному плану.

Он сейчас выступает на конференции, а затем поделится своим опытом работы на семинаре.

Здесь дифференцированные однородные отношения, возможен разный временной план.
Другие примеры ( будущее в настоящем)
— Что сегодня делаешь? — Я сегодня доклад читаю (= буду читать), надо подготовиться. Вот никак литературу к докладу не подберу (= не могу подобрать).
